# How to set PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher's locale in kitkat?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to set PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher's locale.

but in kitkat, can not use PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(String countryCode) constructor.

So i try to use reflection. like this.

```
phoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher = new phoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher();

Field mFormatter = PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.class.getDeclaredField("mFormatter");
mFormatter.setAccessible(true);

mFormatter.set(phoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher, 
PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getAsYouTypeFormatter(COUNTRY_ISO));
```

But mFormatter.set() method throws IllegalArgumentException.

How can i fix it?

---

compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.2'

build.gradle (application)

Comment: Looks like it'd be easier to access the hidden constructor that takes that `String`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/kitkat-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java#71 No clue why it was hidden then.

Comment: Access hidden constructor.. that's a good idea. I'll try!

Answer (score 2):

mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());

this is not work in 21 or higher api. so you should wrap in api lvl condition like this.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("US"));
        }else {
            mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
        }
```

and dont forget to set `inputType="phone"`

this is how you can set locale for higher API only.

Comment: I want to use PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("US") in else case ( under lollipop ) .  
i already used (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) this case .

Comment: well.. its not possible for lower version.. but you can use different library for that.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher's mFormatter is 
com.android.i18n.phonenumbers.AsYouTypeFormatter class but i injected  com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.AsYouTypeFormatter class's instance.  T T